# Why is my setTimeout function to fadeOut, replace and fadeIn text on delay with jquery's replaceWith() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The replacing happens, the fading doesn't... This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var delay = 3000; //3 seconds

setTimeout(function(){
  $('.header p').fadeOut(300, function(){
    $('.header p').replaceWith("<p>A LIFESTYLE FOR EVERYONE</p>");
  });
  $('.header p').fadeIn(300);
}, delay);
console.log("replaced");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the element is problematic when you don't hide new one, change it's content instead

You can avoid multiple dom searches for the same element by chaining things inside the callback of first animation

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $('.header p').fadeOut(300, function(){
            $(this).text("A LIFESTYLE FOR EVERYONE").fadeIn(300);        
     });
}, delay);
```

By only replacing the content it keeps the reference to element and allows chaining

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah...the immediately visible part makes far more sense

Comment: too funny...accept the copied answer that was clearly posted long after this one

Comment: i dont really care what answer I accept. hope you are happy now.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) instead of replaceWith, and put fadeIn inside your callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var delay = 3000; //3 seconds

setTimeout(function(){
  $('.header p').fadeOut(300, function(){
    $('.header p').text("A LIFESTYLE FOR EVERYONE").fadeIn(300);
  });

}, delay);
console.log("replaced");
});
```

If you do replaceWith, you are creating a new p which isn't faded out. Also, you want to fade it in *after* it's faded out (not at the same time).

Comment: Ok awesome! Turns out if I adapted your code it still didnt work, but by making a pen out of it I noticed it did work, and the problem was the local jquery file I had (2.1.3) wasnt working appropriately. the cdn of 2.1.4 did the trick.